# TCP, How to Simulate FIN from both server and Client?

Tags: tcp, telnet

I have to test my application in 2 scenarios .....i.e 
   1. Connection initiator receive FIN from Server
   2. Connection initiator sending FIN to server

I have www server as a server, windows VM as client. I did telnet on 80 to simulate scenario 1. But i need to simulate scenario 2 ...please help me on the same.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Just close the sockets, or if you must, shutdown the socket for output at both ends. That sends a FIN.

But I don't know why you're testing such low level stuff. You should be testing what happens when you or the peer closes the socket, or shuts it down for output: not the operation of the TCP stack.